# React Native release build for Android crashes on startup

Tags: react-native

I've been running into an issue with my React Native app's release builds. The debug builds work just fine and have no issue. When I generate a release build using `gradlew assembleRelase`

I get an APK and it says build successfull. Then I try to install the app on my device using ADB - no problem. But when it comes to running it the app opens for a split second before crashing.

Using `adb logcat`, I can see the following two errors being thrown:

**1) Error getting Google Registration ID - OneSignal/Google Play services**

```
05-09 13:07:33.387 24726 24778 E OneSignal: Error Getting Google Registration ID
05-09 13:07:33.387 24726 24778 E OneSignal: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/zzs;
05-09 13:07:33.387 24726 24778 E OneSignal:     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzaa.zzdr(Unknown Source)
05-09 13:07:33.387 24726 24778 E OneSignal:     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.zza(Unknown Source)
05-09 13:07:33.387 24726 24778 E OneSignal:     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
05-09 13:07:33.387 24726 24778 E OneSignal:     at com.onesignal.PushRegistratorGPS$2.run(PushRegistratorGPS.java:167)
05-09 13:07:33.387 24726 24778 E OneSignal:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-09 13:07:33.387 24726 24778 E OneSignal: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzs" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.***.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.***.app-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.***.app-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
05-09 13:07:33.387 24726 24778 E OneSignal:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
05-09 13:07:33.387 24726 24778 E OneSignal:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
05-09 13:07:33.387 24726 24778 E OneSignal:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
05-09 13:07:33.387 24726 24778 E OneSignal:     ... 5 more
05-09 13:07:33.387 24726 24778 E OneSignal:     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzs
05-09 13:07:33.387 24726 24778 E OneSignal:             at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
05-09 13:07:33.387 24726 24778 E OneSignal:             at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
05-09 13:07:33.387 24726 24778 E OneSignal:             at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
05-09 13:07:33.387 24726 24778 E OneSignal:             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
05-09 13:07:33.387 24726 24778 E OneSignal:             ... 6 more
05-09 13:07:33.387 24726 24778 E OneSignal:     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

To me it seems like the google play services libraries are not being loaded in correctly, but I have added them to my app's `build.gradle` like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(path: ':react-native-onesignal')
    compile project(path: ':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(path: ':react-native-config')

    implementation (project(':react-native-maps')) {
        //Exclude support-v4 module from react-native-maps plugin because a more recent version is pulled in by another dependency
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'

        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }

    compile (project(':react-native-geolocation-service')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-location'
    }

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
}
```

**2) Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module**

```
05-09 13:07:34.253 24726 24759 E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication), stack:
05-09 13:07:34.253 24726 24759 E AndroidRuntime: value@23:3441
05-09 13:07:34.253 24726 24759 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@23:1067
05-09 13:07:34.253 24726 24759 E AndroidRuntime: value@23:3009
05-09 13:07:34.253 24726 24759 E AndroidRuntime: value@23:1039
05-09 13:07:34.253 24726 24759 E AndroidRuntime:
05-09 13:07:34.253 24726 24759 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:54)
05-09 13:07:34.253 24726 24759 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:38)
05-09 13:07:34.253 24726 24759 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-09 13:07:34.253 24726 24759 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
05-09 13:07:34.253 24726 24759 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:160)
05-09 13:07:34.253 24726 24759 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
05-09 13:07:34.253 24726 24759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
05-09 13:07:34.253 24726 24759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-09 13:07:34.253 24726 24759 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
05-09 13:07:34.253 24726 24759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
05-09 13:07:34.253 24726 24759 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)
05-09 13:07:34.253 24726 24759 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-09 13:07:34.255 24726 24759 D AppTracker: App Event: crash
```

Here it seems that it can't find the registered component, however in my index.js I registered the component like so:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('SpotsApp', () => App);
```

Where `App` is the actual application component. Inside my build.gradle I point to this file as the entry file:

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]
```

And inside my `MainApplication` I set the main module name like so:

```
@Override
protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
    return "App";
}
```

For the first error it seems to me like the google play services are imported correctly and added as dependencies. For the second error I believe I register my component correctly, yet I keep running into these issues with release build. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As for your second issue, `getJSMainModuleName` should point to `index`, not `App`. Eg. `@Override protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }`

Comment: Are you sure? `App.js` contains my actual component, i.e. `class App extends React.Component` which is my root component, while `index.js` just contains the `AppRegistry.registerComponent` line. I will try it anyway and report back.

Comment: @Eran you were right, that was another issue. I also noticed that my `getMainComponentName` in MainActivity was incorrect, had to change something there too. Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it - it definitely pointed me in the right direction! Both errors are fixed now. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear :) Posted as answer to help anybody who might come across this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)` is caused by a misconfiguration of the main JS module name.

To fix, simply refer to the entry point of the application rather than the app component itself.

Eg.

```
@Override
protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
    return "index"; // Was: App
}
```

Also, make sure that in `MainActivity.java` the method `getMainComponentName` returns the name of the component you've registered in your index file.

Answer (score 0):

For the first error regarding the NoClassDefFoundError for OneSignal/Google Play services: it seems as if it is specifically the `OneSignal` react native library that is conflicting with something (not quite sure what). After some digging I found [this comment (link to Github)](https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/blob/master/android/build.gradle#L74) hidden in the react-native-onesignal library:

```
// Add the following to the top (Line 1) of your app/build.gradle if you run into any issues with duplicate classes.
// Such as the following error
//   Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms.license'

/*
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.8.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
*/
```

So I followed those instructions. I added these lines to the start of my app's build.gradle (so before the `apply plugin: "com.android.application"` line):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.8.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

This solution fixes the problem with the NoClassDefFoundError / DexMultiPath error. The solution was not at all documented on the OneSignal website and I had to dig through their build.gradle, that is why I decided to post it here as an answer.

---

I have not yet found a solution to the second error which means my app still crashes on startup, but the first error is resolved. I will edit this answer when I find the solution to my second error.